# Longest non repetitive path in a graph?

Tags: graph-algorithm, dijkstra, directed-acyclic-graphs

I was working on to find the shortest path between two nodes in undirected acyclic graph using Dijkstra's algorithms. I wanted to find the longest path that is possible by the same algorithm. I also want to avoid few routes with 0 edge values. How do I do that using Dijkstra's algorithm?

Now after searching through Stackoverflow I came across one given solution which just states that we need to modify the relaxation part to find the longest path.

Like:

```
if(distanceValueOfNodeA< EdgeValueofNodeBtoA )

{

distanceValueOfNodeA = EdgeValueofNodeBtoA;

}
```

But we are not considering adding `distanceValueOfNodeB`

But for shortest paths we calculate:

```
distanceValueOfNodeA = distanceValueOfNodeB+EdgeValueofNodeBtoA
```

Should we ignore `distanceValueOfNodeB` to calculate `distanceValueOfNodeA` ?

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry to disappoint you but that problem is known as [Longest path in a graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) and there isn't an efficient algorithm to solve it, so niether Djikstra algorithm with any modification can.

It belongs to a class of problems known as NP-hard,those are problems for which there isn't (at the moment) an algorithm to solve them in faster time complexity compared to exponential.